# iad on spitview controller

Tags: iphone, iad, ipad

can we add iad on ipad splitviewcontroller?
if yes how?

thanks,
shyam paramr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find a splitview and add it

[self.splitviewcontroller addSubView:_ad];

its not going to resize as per mode.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you use predefined constants to set the size of your iAd view. These constants are generally representative of the width of the screen and then a small height, about 65 pixels. It would seem then, that iAd is *not* compatible with the UISplitViewController.

I suggest taking a peek at [the iAd AdBannerView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Content_Size_Identifiers). It may help you achieve what you want. (You can try putting iAd beneath the splitviewcontroller, since a view is a view, no matter what subclass it of uiviewcontroller it is.)

Answer (score 1):

In the [iAdSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) Apple sample code there is a split view controller iAd implementation which you can easily add into your application. :^)